# -bash: [: too many arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell

How do I get rid of this on my bash terminal?

I suspect that the code that triggers this is found in my `.bash_profile`:

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Removing the line above, gives me back a prompt that Rails cannot be found, even if I have rails installed.

Comment: Check your environment for `$PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: Basically correct, but note that `PROMPT_COMMAND` will not be necessarily stored in the **environment** of the process, i.e. it won't necessarily show up when you search for it using `env` or `printenv`. It's best to check for it with `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: @JuanTomas, what do you mean particularly? I am very new to bash.

Comment: @user1934428, i typed in `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` and it returned `prompt command` .

Comment: That's probably significant, usually `$PROMPT_COMMAND` is not set.  Your shell will execute `prompt command` (whatever that is) before each command you enter in the shell.  Try `which prompt`.  When it tells you what file is `prompt`, you can `cat` the file.

Comment: @AnnaS: It returned the string *prompt command* (with one space in between)?????. In any case, you have to find out, where this variable is set.

Comment: @user1934428, Thanks for pointing out the typo. It is `prompt_command`. 
Attaching `unset $PROMPT_COMMAND` to the end of my `.bash_profile` removed the bash message. 
However, it proved troublesome as the prompts for `master` and `my_branch_name` also did not display as I switched between the two during development.

Comment: I would not unset it, but fix `prompt_command` itself. I guess the command was originally written for a different shell (or shell version) than you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue after running `rvm get stable`.

Since `rvm` needs to run in the shell session as a function, removing the line `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` from your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` is not an option as it will cause gems to not be found.

On my environment the cause was due to a conflict between an old installation of [bash-it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it) and rvm. If you're using `bash-it` and encountering this issue, this may help.

I took the following steps:

1. Backed up my `.bash_profile` (if you have `.bashrc` you may want to back it up as well).
2. Ran `bash-it`'s uninstall script (see instructions in the link above) and removed `~/.bash-it` folder.
3. Reinstalled `bash-it`.
4. Added to `.bash_profile` what was missing based on my `.bash_profile` backup created on step 1.
5. Reenabled the `bash-it` aliases, completions, and plugins that I needed.

As soon as I opened a new shell, I stopped receiving the error and `rvm` started working properly.